# Views not displaying properly in Partner Portal due to certain fields

Tags: partner-portal, custom-view

We use an app called Click-to-Call. It adds a few fields that let you do things like dial a phone number using Skype with a click. We have some views set up that use it in our normal org and it works great.

We recently set up a partner portal, and these fields, when included in a view, mess up the entire formatting of the view.

Without the Click to Call field, looking pretty normal:
[image]

With the Click to Call field... umm...[image]?

If it's not clear, instead of a list, the records are all going horizontal (And the field still isn't there).

Any idea why this happens in Partner Portal but not in the regular org? Any ideas on how to fix it? The field in question, Click-to-Call Phone, is simply a formula field. Here is the formula it uses:

```
IF(Phone != null, HYPERLINK("skype:"+IF( ClickToDial__Country_Code__c != null,ClickToDial__Country_Code__c, $Setup.ClickToDial__ConfigurationManager__c.ClickToDial__Global_Country_Code__c ) & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Phone, '-', ''),' ' ,''),')',''),'(',''),'.',''),',','') +"?call", IF( ClickToDial__Country_Code__c != null,ClickToDial__Country_Code__c, $Setup.ClickToDial__ConfigurationManager__c.ClickToDial__Global_Country_Code__c ) & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Phone, '-', ''),' ' ,''),')',''),'(',''),'.',''),',','') , "_self\" onclick=\"createTask('"+ Phone +"', '"+ Id +"','"+ $Api.Session_ID +"',true,'"+ $User.Id +"','"+$Setup.ClickToDial__ConfigurationManager__c.ClickToDial__EnableAutoCallLog__c+"');\" "),'')
```

Looking at the HTML generated, it seems to not ever be creating a new TR, it's just one table row with lots of TH and TDs. The anchor tag is self closing. My guess right now is that the Partner Portal doesn't have access to some of the fields in the formula, most likely the ones related to Setup. I'm still very new to Partner Portal and trying to figure this stuff out.

**UPDATE:** This may be more of an issue with Internet Explorer than with Salesforce or Click-to-Call. When I run this in Chrome it works just fine.

Comment: Strange.  Maybe you can use the developer tools to inspect the DOM or anything else (F12 in IE9).

Comment: I talked to SFDC support - they basically said IE is not supported and that sometimes things don't display properly when using that browser.